# iPad2 home screen icon dimensions?

Tags: ios, ipad, ipad-2

What dimensions should I save a bookmark icon for iPad2?

I know the original iPad uses 72 x 72.  Is it the same for iPad2?  I can't find any info on this.

iPhone 4's icon dimensions went up to 114 x 114 (from 57 x 57 in older iPhones), and I'm wondering if something similar happened with iPad2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iPad 2 has the same resolution as the first iPad. 72x72 will do it.